# Android Developer Console screenshots being cropped. Anyone else having this issue? Advise?

Tags: android, console, google-play, screenshot

When uploading 480x800 or 480x854 png or jpgs to the Android Market Developer console, the images in the console appear poorly scaled and chopped off on the left side. Upon clicking the image you see the "real" thing.

Problem is what you see in the console is also what appears in the Android Market (till user actually clicks on the thumbnail) !!!! So users are seeing images that are chopped off on the left side.

There is some text next to the screenshot upload area in the dev console that reads: "The thumbnails will appear to be cropped, but the actual images will be preserved." But again, the problem is that customers are seeing the cropped image in the main Market listing for the app. If user then clicks on an image they see the uncropped image.

Please let me know if you have a way to get 480x800 or 480x854 images uploaded without them getting chopped.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is. We just stick to 320x480 images in our apps.

Comment: Yeah, I've resorted to 320x480 for now. It just seems kind of crazy that Google, multi-billion dollar company, can't spend the time to fix this kind of thing.